# Пропадают надписи в шапке таблицы

Tags: php

Проблема следующая, есть шапка и строки, вот так вот выводятся все строки, но в шапке пропадают участки и кабинеты, хотя по условию если есть они то и в шапке должны надписи появляться.

```
$myCmd = "SELECT * FROM dlpodrazdeleniya, dldoctor, dlSpec, dltime WHERE id='$cat' AND dldoctor.idPodr = dlpodrazdeleniya.idPodr AND dldoctor.SpecID =  dlSpec.SpecID AND dldoctor.DoctorID =  dltime.DoctorID";$buf = mysql_query($myCmd);echo "<table  class='sortable1' id='table'>\n";
            echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
            if (!empty($buf['Ychastok'])) {
            echo "<th>Участок</th>\n";
            }
            if (!empty($buf['Cabinet'])) {
            echo "<th>Кабинет</th>\n";
        }
            echo "<th>ФИО врача</th>\n";
            echo "<th>Специалист</th>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";

for($i=1; $i<=mysql_num_rows($buf); $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($buf);

            echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
            if (!empty($row['Ychastok'])) {
            echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['Ychastok']."</td>\n";
            }

            if (!empty($row['Cabinet'])) {
            echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['Cabinet']."</td>\n";
            }
            echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['LastName']." ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']."</td>\n";
            echo "<td><font color=red>".$row['SpecName']."</font color></td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";

    }               
 echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Жутко оформленный код. Его бы сначала в порядок привести, а потом людям показывать.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на то, что такое **`$buf`** и **`$row`** - они ведь являются результатами работы разных функций.

Функция [**`mysql_query`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) возвращает **не массив**, а ресурс, поэтому всякие `$buf['Что-то-там']` будут возвращать `null`.

В то же время [**`mysql_fetch_array`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) возвращает как раз **массив**, и уже в нём можно проверять, есть поле или нет.

*А код и правда страшненький. Представляю, как вы потом будете дизайн менять. Люди ведь давно придумали шаблонизаторы.*